# Python Requests - managing cookies

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests

I'm trying to get some content automatically from a site using requests (and bs4)

I have a script that gets a cookie:

```
def getCookies(self):
    username = 'username'
    password = 'password'
    URL = 'logonURL'
    r = requests.get(URL, auth=('username', 'password'))
    cookies = r.cookies
```

dump of the cookies looks like:

```
<<class 'requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar'>[<Cookie ASP.NET_SessionId=yqokjr55ezarqbijyrwnov45 for URL.com/>, <Cookie BIGipServerPE_Journals.lww.com_80=1440336906.20480.0000 for URL.com/>, <Cookie JournalsLockCookie=id=a5720750-3f20-4207-a500-93ae4389213c&ip=IP address for URL.com/>]>
```

But when I pass the cookie object to the next URL:

```
 soup = Soup(s.get(URL, cookies = cookies).content)
```

its not working out - I can see by dumping the soup that I'm not giving the webserver my credentials properly

I tried running a requests session:

```
def getCookies(self):
    self.s = requests.session()
    username = 'username'
    password = 'password'
    URL = 'logURL'
    r = self.s.get(URL, auth=('username', 'password'))
```

and I get the same no joy.

I looked at the header via liveHttp in FF when I visit the 2nd page, and see a very different form:

```
Cookie: WT_FPC=id=264b0aa85e0247eb4f11355304127862:lv=1355317068013:ss=1355314918680; UserInfo=Username=username; BIGipServerPE_Journals.lww.com_80=1423559690.20480.0000; PlatformAuthCookie=true; Institution=ReferrerUrl=http://logonURL.com/?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=urn:adis&wctx=http://URL.com/_layouts/Authenticate.aspx?Source=%252fpecnews%252ftoc%252f2012%252f06440&token=method|ExpireAbsolute; counterSessionGuidId=6e2bd57f-b6da-4dd4-bcb0-742428e08b5e; MyListsRefresh=12/13/2012 12:59:04 AM; ASP.NET_SessionId=40a04p45zppozc45wbadah45; JournalsLockCookie=id=85d1f38f-dcbb-476a-bc2e-92f7ac1ae493&ip=10.204.217.84; FedAuth=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
```

I have redacted the username, password, and URLS from the question for obvious reasons.

Am I missing something obvious? is there a different / proper way to capture the cookie - the current method I'm using is not working.

EDIT:

This is a self standing version of the sessioned code:

```
s = requests.session()
username = 'username'
password = 'password'
URL = 'logonURL.aspx'
r = s.get(URL, auth=('username', 'password'))
URL = r"URL.aspx"
soup = Soup(s.get(URL).content)
```

reading a dump of the soup, I can see in the html that its telling me I don't have access - this string only appears via browser when you're not logged in.

Comment: Are you sure that the authentication process is in fact a GET request, and not a POST?

Comment: A very good question. How would I tell? (liveHTTP says: GET /ig_res/default/ig_dialogwindow.css HTTP/1.1)

Comment: If you're trying to "login" to a site, try logging in using a normal browser, and observe the requests that are sent to the server. If you've got Chrome, you can use the built-in developer tools. If you're using Firefox, you can use Firebug. As a side note, most form-based submissions (e.g. a login form) are POST requests.

Comment: No, that's a CSS (stylesheet) file. Try just using a POST and see what happens. As in, `r = s.post(URL, auth=('username', 'password'))` in your session-based request.

Comment: I logged out, then logged in again. The first header I see is a GET /ig_res/default/ig_dialogwindow.css HTTP/1.1 that has an object called `Cookie: WT_FPC=id= etc` its the same string I offered previously. I guess that makes it a POST header...

Comment: OK. I tried that, same thing. "You currently do not have access to this article"

Comment: No, it doesn't. A post request begins with POST. What you are seeing is a GET request for the stylesheet (your browser is asking the server for the stylesheet, so that it can display the page nicely).

Comment: Are you trying to POST to the page that you want to retrieve? You need to POST to the login URL first, _then_ GET the page that you need (using the same session).

Comment: Aye, I POSTed the credentials. I'll hit it again, just to make sure! Yupe. No joy. Thanks though! I appreciate your pointers.

Answer (score 24):

I had a similar problem and found help in this question. The session jar was empty and to actually get the cookie I needed to use a session.

```
session = requests.session()
p = session.post("http://example.com", {'user':user,'password':password})
print 'headers', p.headers
print 'cookies', requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar(session.cookies)
print 'html',  p.text
```

Answer (score 7):

You should be reusing the whole *session* object, not the associated cookiejar. Use `self.s` for all requests you make.

If your requests are still failing when reusing the session, they will be failing for a different reason, not because you are not properly returning cookies.

Note that if you need to use `auth=('username', 'password')` then the authentication is HTTPAuth-based, not cookie-based. You need to pass in the same authentication for all calls. The requests session can do that for you too:

```
s = requests.session(auth=('username', 'password'))
```

If, however, the login page is a form with a username and password field, you'll need to call the form target instead. Check if the form is POST or GET, and check the fieldnames:

```
s.post(loginTarget, {usernamefield=username, passwordfield=password, otherfield=othervalue})
```

and not use HTTP authentication at all.

Comment: I added a self standing example of the sessioned version - is that correct?