# Python requests: requests.get returns 404 on valid url

Tags: python, google-play, python-requests

I am trying to get apps which are similar to an app from the Google Play Store in python, using the requests API.

This returns a happy 200:

```
payload = {"id":"apk_name"}
requests.get("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details", params = payload)
```

This returns a 404:

```
requests.get("http://play.google.com/store/apps/similar", params = payload)
```

The last request produces a valid url for both Chrome and postman, how could I create a valid request for similar apps?

To make matters more interesting, was testing this in my terminal, it worked twice in a row, then went back to replying with a 404.

Comment: Forgot a little part in my question. 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/similar?id=com.stackexchange.marvin is correct.

Comment: I still get a 404 in the browser for that.

Comment: So either the URL is only available on *some* servers and not all, or a login is required, or a referer or some other request header aspect that is missing for me and for your `requests.get()` call. Try accessing the URL in a Incognito (private) browser session.

Comment: Seems like you're onto something there. Though the standard requests authentication doesn't work.
    requests.get("http://play.google.com/store/apps/similar", params = payload,auth=('user', 'pass'))

Comment: The Google Play site doesn't use basic auth, no. It uses a session-based (cookie based) authentication.

Comment: You helped me solve it, thanks. Used your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/13854790/4658520

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by using the answer here 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13854790/4658520

Issue was using session, not HttpAuth