# Using urllib instead of wget for session authentication

Tags: python

So currently i have a line of python code which uses wget and os.system to download a file from a website. However when i try to convert this wget to a more elegant library such as urllib or requests, the cookies fail to authenticate and instead downloads the login html page instead of the file.

Here is what i currently use:

```
    try:
         print(URL)
         os.system(
            "wget --save-cookies cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies --post-data='name={}&password={}' https://fakesite/login".format(
                username, password))
         os.system("wget --load-cookies cookies.txt --accept=exe {}".format(URL))

    except Exception as e:
         print(" File not found, please refer to the website manually for download link", e)
```

which i attempted to refactor into something like this:

```
    try:
    print("Downloading file {} version: {}......".format(version, buildNo))
    with requests.session() as s:
        s.post(loginUrl, data="name:{}&password:{}".format(username,password))
        print(URL)
        r = s.get(URL,cookies=s.cookies, headers={"Accept": "application/octet-stream"})
        print (r.content)
```

but this fails and instead prints the html content of the login page! can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Check this perhaps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13854735/python-requests-managing-cookies#19129354

Comment: I have tried the way you try and it didn't work because the login was not successful (changed data to data={"username":"some username", "password":"password"} but that's api specific ). Two questions, what is the status_code of the login response and second is the accept correct? Also, in the wget example, you send name and not username.

Comment: i get a 302 response, but i have altered the get request to allow redirects and it still fails to follow through. Also i noticed the username issue as soon as i posted this but still didnt resolve my issue :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `=` instead `:` in your query:

```
s.post(loginUrl, data="name={}&password={}".format(username,password))
```

Also, you could (and should, following the `requests` best practice) proceed a dict to `data` argument:

```
s.post(
    loginUrl,
    data={
        'name': username,
        'password': password,
    }
)
```