# Find out what cookies to set on different websites using Python

Tags: python, cookies, web-scraping, python-requests

I have a list of about 10.000 URLs pointing to online news articles. I have written some code to scrape the html-content of these news articles, using the Requests-library (Python 3.5). The goal is to retrieve the article content using the Readability-module and perform further analysis on that. This works most of the time. However, all websites are in Dutch and so are subject to the EU policy stating they have to ask for consent to use cookies. Some of them, for example http://telegraaf.nl, do this by loading a separate page where the user has to click a button. In this case, I can get the normal article content by passing a cookie in the header:

```
import requests

user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0'
url = 'http://www.telegraaf.nl/dft/geld/werk-inkomen/27740808/__Vechten_om_werk_in_noorden__.html'
cookies_telegraaf = {'TMGCOOKIE': '{%22version%22:%22t3%22}'}
html = requests.get(url, headers={"User-Agent": user_agent}, cookies=cookies_telegraaf)
print(html.content)
```

This prints the html-content I need. The problem is, every site needs a different cookie. So my question is: is there a way to find out what specific cookie to pass in the header for each website, without manually checking in the browser?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is more like a comment than a real answer. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13854735/python-requests-managing-cookies?rq=1) is another answer that might help.
What I would do is to deal with sites that work without cookies first, then try to deal those who don't load a separate page, then those with separate page.
However if your question is to know if there is a way to access to cookies easily, requests documentation gives a method for that, [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#cookies):

```
 url = 'http://example.com/some/cookie/setting/url'
>>> r = requests.get(url)

>>> r.cookies['example_cookie_name']
'example_cookie_value'
```

To send your own cookies to the server, you can use the cookies parameter:

```
>>> url = 'http://httpbin.org/cookies'
>>> cookies = dict(cookies_are='working')

>>> r = requests.get(url, cookies=cookies)
>>> r.text
'{"cookies": {"cookies_are": "working"}}'
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. Sites without cookies or without a separate page asking for consent work fine, so I can deal with those. Your method for accessing cookies sadly won't work, it seems: I have to actively set a specific cookie implying that I accept cookies from the webpage (I won't go into the irony of that here). Sometimes it might be 'accept_cookies' set to '1', another site uses different formatting. The only way I have of knowing that at the moment is to click the 'accept cookies' button, and then check my browser settings to see what new cookie was set.

Comment: @Kevin If that's the case you would probably need to simulate the browser with libraries like `selenium`. Is there a common element in the accept buttons of the pages, maybe something like "input type='submit'" or something like that, if so you can try to pinpoint them to selenium to automatically click on them and receive cookies ?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try out Selenium and report the results. Sadly, some use a button and others just use a hyperlink. But there's usually only one or very few on a page, so a bit of extra coding might do the job. I'll let you know when I know more.

Comment: Did you ever find a suitable solution to this?